# JavaScript using enter to run field search

Tags: javascript, button, search, scripting

I'm pretty new to programming and everthing and right now i am trying to improve some internal programs and script. One of those things is our booking system. Its using JS and field search to search through all the projects but it doesnt work when pressing enter instead of clicking the button.
I tried using a tapermonkey script to fix it but it doesnt catch the input value when pressing enter.

This is the input and the search button:

```
<input name="b$s111$l108s111$ctl00$googlesearch$i" 
type="text" 
maxlength="3998" 
id="b_s111_l108s111_ctl00_googlesearch_i" 
class="Edit" 
onfocus="HighlightTextBox(this, 'b$s111$l108s111$ctl00$googlesearch', false, false);" 
datavalidation="false" 
data-sectionid="111" 
data-fieldid="1841" 
onchange="setDirty('b_s111_l108s111_ctl00_googlesearch_IsDirty');
if(!IsLegalInputValue(this,'Search criteria')){return false;}" 
onblur="if(!IsLegalInputValue(this,'Search criteria')){return false;}ResetTextBox(this, 'b$s111$l108s111$ctl00$googlesearch', false, false, 'white');" 
onkeydown="CheckForShiftTab(event);if(event.keyCode == 9 &amp;&amp; !event.ctrlKey){if(!IsLegalInputValue(this,'Search criteria')){return false;}}" 
data-type="String" 
autocomplete="off" 
>

<button id="b_s111__fieldHelpSearch" 
tabindex="10" 
role="button" 
type="button" 
class="BaseButton SectionButton" 
onclick="baseButtonClick(event, 'b$s111$_fieldHelpSearch', true, 'action:_dofieldhelpsearch');" 
onkeydown="this.onclick(event);"
>
```

And this is the script I wrote:

```
  var input = document.getElementById("b_s111_l108s111_ctl00_googlesearch_i");
     input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("b_s111__fieldHelpSearch").click();
  }
});
```

Why is the search not working right and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value inside the input box, then I don't think this line makes sense `document.getElementById("b_s111__fieldHelpSearch").click();`
Instead you can do:

```
const input = document.getElementById('b_s111_l108s111_ctl00_googlesearch_i')
input.addEventListener('keydown',(e)=>{
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this this solves at least the one problem.
But I still can't figure out how to use the value to actually search for it unfortunately.

I think my problem is, that i can't figure out which function to run to actually search

Comment: Are you using external API to search? If so then, instead of console logging ```console.log(e.target.value) ``` you can call another function passing the ```e.target.value``` as an parameter which in turn makes api request. If it helps then consider upvoting the answer. Thank you!